# Exception when trying to save user email and name in to the Firebase DB

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im working on a project in swift 3.0 and I'm getting the following **exception** when trying to save two string values in to the Firebase DB.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidFirebaseData', reason: '(updateChildValues:withCompletionBlock:) Cannot store object of type _SwiftValue at . Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray.'

The code of the class as bellow. **What am I missing ?**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var userNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var userEmailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passWordTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
//   
   }
@IBAction func loginPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
 FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: userEmailTextField.text!, password: passWordTextField.text!, completion: { (user :FIRUser?, error) in
             if error != nil {

                print("error in login")
                return
             }else{
             print("loggin success")

             let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: "https://chatsample-4cc11.firebaseio.com/")
                let values = ["username" : self.userNameTextField.text, "email" : self.userEmailTextField.text]
                ref.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
                    if err != nil {
                    print(err)
                        return
                    }
                    print("saved user successfully to firebase DB")
                })
                //ref.updateChildValues(values)
             //ref.updateChildValues(["somevalue": 123123])

             }
            })
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is you didn't unwrap the values of username and email, so these values were type of Optional. You should change to

```
let values = ["username" : self.userNameTextField.text!, "email" : self.userEmailTextField.text!]
```